# Difficulty with height balance in AVL tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

[image]

In this figure x,y,z are the nodes on which rotation is performed and T1, T2, T3, T4 are the subtrees.
I have understood how the rotation is working and have no trouble with that. The problem I am having is determining the final balance factor of nodes in the tree.
In the first case before rotation, the balance of factor of x will be +2 or -2(that's why we are performing the rotation). But what about the balance factor of y? Why is it always taken as +1 or -1? Why it can't be 0(the height of T3 can be equal to the height of z)? What will we the balance factor of z? It can be anything right? In short, what will be the balance factor of nodes with the question mark?

This is the code I am trying to write:

```
Node insert(Node node, int key)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        node = new Node(key);

    else if (key <= node->key)
    {
        node->balance++;
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    }

    else if (key > node->key)
    {
        node->balance--;
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);  
    }

    // Right Tree Heavy
    if (node->balance == -2) 
    { 
        /*Do the required rotation and update the balance factor*/
    }

    // Left Tree Heavy
    if (node->balance == 2) 
    {
         /*Do the required rotation and update the balance factor*/
    }

    return node;
}
```

Edit: Initially the tree was satisfying all the properties of avl tree. Then a new node was added to either T1 or T2 which made the tree unbalanced at node x. Can anyone explain all the cases of balance factor of nodes before and after the rotation.